# Monadic construction of a chain of partial functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, set, combinations, monads

Consider a set of `n` numbers (e.g. 4 numbers`{1, 2, 3, 4}`), and a set of some binary `{+, -, *, /}` and unary operators `{ln, exp, sin}`. Combine these using each number *once*, using any operators where a number can be applied to a unary operator at most once. For example: `1+2+3-4` or `sin(1)*4 + log(2) + 3`. Now, **compute** all possible expressions, showing all expressions whose results are over `0`.

We could chain them up as using prefix operations into point-free style functions like this in Haskell:

```
(+) 1 . (+) 2 . (-) 3 $ 4
(+) 3 . (+) (log 2) . (*) 4 $ (sin 1)
```

Is there functor/monad/applicative oriented approach to get all possible chains that combine each number with all possible operators, without repeating mathematically equivalent expressions w.r.t. the commutative properties of those binary operators, for example, `1+2=2+1`, `2*3=3*2`?

Comment: Wait, what is the *non*-idiomatic way? Is this a disguised form of some common problem? Could you elaborate on the particular use case? Also I assume something like `sin (exp (sin 1))` is not allowed and you can only: either leave the element as is or apply one unary op?

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematically equivalent expressions"? `sin(0)` is equal to `0+1+2-3`; does that make the expressions "mathematically equivalent" in your view? Do you expect to deal with exact equality, or some approximation? If the former, you may need to use something like [symengine](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/symengine).

Comment: Also, your current formulation seems to allow an infinite number of results: `[2, ln 2, ln (ln 2), ln (ln (ln 2)), ...]`. Did you mean to limit expressions to at most one use of each unary operator?

Comment: Finally, once you get past all those questions, I suggest you consider something like the list monad, or perhaps the `Logic` monad (from the `logict` package).

Comment: @user2847643 By saying "idiomatic" I meant to constrain the question so procedural and/or too low-level methods will be excluded, and will be more like monadic/functor oriented answer. And thanks! I updated the question!

Comment: @dfeuer I specified what I meant by equivalent, and I am sorry for not being specific there at first. I have the list monad in mind, and actually tried this by constructing `String`s in the reverse polish notation, then evaluating them. However, using chains of functions seems to be a far better approach.

Comment: I don't think chains of functions or RPN is a good approach. I think you should instead use an AST for an expression. Something like `data Expr b u n = Lit n | Bin (Expr b u n) b (Expr b u n)  | App u (Expr b u n)`. When you're generating a `Bin`, you can generate the left argument and use it to limit the right argument. If the the right argument is constrained to be "no smaller than" the left one according to some total order (the one expressed by `deriving Ord` is probably the one you want) then you take care of commutativity. You can pass down the lists of available literals and unary ops.

Comment: So, build up this `Expr` AST myself, then traverse through it? Seems like reinventing something, while the list monad gives some of the stuff I was looking for.

Comment: I think you should use the list monad! I just think you should represent your expressions using an AST. You want to make lists of expressions, right?

Comment: Yes, lists of expressions.

Comment: You might like to adapt [this code for 24 puzzles](http://pic.blog.plover.com/math/24-puzzle/blechschmidt-solver.txt); there is also some [discussion](http://blog.plover.com/math/24-puzzle.html) of pitfalls to avoid when cooking up your own solution from scratch.

Comment: @DanielWagner The link you provided seems very close to what I was trying to implement, but I was looking for a much shorter, more ideally, a one-liner, approach to this (while being able to import standard modules).